# How can i refresh jupyter-lab tqdm output?

Tags: python, jupyter-lab, tqdm

After running the code on the server, I want to check the progress when i come back later, so How can i refresh the output progress bar? is there no way?

[image]

Looking at any menu, there was no refresh of cell output.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What exactly have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) .. how are you calling tqdm? are you navigating away from the notebook instance and coming back later?